# checked md-radio-group on pageload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, material-design, angular-material

I am creating a web app in mvc-5

I have taken radio button of material designing. Here is my radio button:

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="mdgender" ng-change="changeradio()" ng-init="mdgender.Datewise='Datewise'">
    <md-radio-button ng-model="mdgender.Datewise" ng-checked="1==1" value="Datewise" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">Date wise</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button ng-model="mdgender.CompanyWise" value="CompanyWise" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">Company Wise</md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

I want the 1st radio button to be checked on page load, but I am unable to do this.

> 1 I tried `ng-checked=true;`
>
> 2 `ng-init="mdgender.Datewise='Datewise'";`

but I am still not able to solve this.

What do I need to do if I want my first radio button to be checked on pageload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set **ng-model** of `<md-radio-group>`

```
<md-radio-group ng-model="mdgender" ng-change="changeradio()" ng-init="mdgender='Datewise'">
```

**Here**

`ng-model="mdgender"` in md-radio-group has to be initialized to `ng-init="mdgender='Datewise'"`

Plunker [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/JbyKfSsR4N3jeuFqkJWw?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add:

```
ng-class="{'md-checked': your_expression}"
```

Seems like ng-checked is not working with md-radio-button

Comment: what i need to write here? (your_expression)

Comment: An expression that evaluates to true if you want the button to be marked as checked. Check the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: so can i set ng-class="{'md-checked': true}"??

Comment: I am Really New In This, Sorry for this